# Is it possible to get coverage statistics on C++ headers files with specialised templates in them?

Tags: unit-testing, googletest, gcov, gcovr

I hope you can help. Ive have spend the day researching this problem and have yet to find a solution.

I have a header file which contains specialized templates inside them and I would like to make sure my unit tests are covering it properly.

I am using gtest as my test framework. Once the tests have been run, I open up my class up in CoverStory to see the stats. The cpp file is fine, but the h file has problems. I can see the percentage of coverage there but there is no code preview. Every line says /*EOF*/

Is this normal? I believe it is, ive never seen a header file load up properly in CoverStory.

My next step is to run gcovr on the results, the output xml file is then passed onto cobertura, which does not even recognise a header file as being present. Ive had a look into the xml file and there is not mention of the header file either.

Many Thanks